# Looking for node.js user agent function

Tags: node.js, user-agent

Im looking for a node.js function, which checks if the user agent is "mozilla/5.0" and reply you are allowed and all other user agents do not get reply.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to this post about accessing headers in AWS Lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287482/6476735

Comment: no... im not using express. im trying to find a nodejs function which can be used in AWS lambda that satisfies above condition.

Comment: I edited my answer to point to another post that shows you what to do.