# Access headers in AWS Lambda function passed from Mule Amazon Lambda Connector

Tags: aws-lambda, mule, aws-lambda-edge

I am calling the AWS Lambda function through a mule connector, internally it is creating a Authentication and signedHeader with signiture. Something as below ( This I got form the debug log)

```
customerHeader: headerValue
accept: application/json
X-Amz-Date: 20210716T073050Z
Host: lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={Key}/{Date}/{Region}/{Service}
SignedHeaders=accept;content-length;content-type;customheader;x-amz-date Signature=0989f7a09sf9asf90a3fj30a0fa248290rjfiajf
```

But when I try to print the event in lambda funtion, it just prints the body but no header. I don't to pass the headers through api-gateway. What can be done in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to access those headers?

Comment: Need to pass correlationId and some other headers from Mule api

Comment: Looks like your question is unrelated to the client, in this case an API implemented in Mule runtime, but it could be whatever other client. The question seems to point to how to read HTTP headers from AWS Lambda side. There are previous answers about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access header in AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286197/how-to-access-header-in-aws-lambda)

Comment: After using connector for a while, I understood that the connector does not modify the lambda response as the aws gateway does. I was expecting lambda headers in the http header response which is actually wrong. Had to modify lambda response to and then do basic transformation to differentiate between attributes, body and statusCode